# Java Synth XML: Button Style properties won't work

Tags: java, xml, swing, button, synth

I'm new to XML - and new to Java Synth LAF...

I have loaded the following XML style file correctly to my UIManager:

```
<synth>
<style id="default">
    <font name="Segoe UI" size="16"/>
</style>
<bind style="default" type="region" key=".*"/>

<style id="button">
    <opaque value="true">
        <insets top="10" bottom="10" left="10" right="10"/>
        <state>
            <color type="BACKGROUND" value="#FFFFFF"/>
            <color type="TEXT_FOREGROUND" value="#000000"/>
        </state>
    </opaque>
</style>
<bind style="button" type="region" key="Button"/>
```

The default style works fine but the button style doesn't work for some reason.

Thanks in advance

Comment: -> I added the opaque true tag because I found that solution on the internet but it doesnt work neither with true nor with false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The opaque element - Synth File Format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/synth/doc-files/synthFileFormat.html#e.opaque)

The `opaque` element is empty elements  because it is declared with the category keyword `EMPTY`.

```
<!ELEMENT opaque EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST opaque
          value              (true|false)   "true"
>
```

```
<synth>
  <style id="default">
    <font name="Segoe UI" size="16"/>
  </style>
  <bind style="default" type="region" key=".*"/>

  <style id="button">
    <opaque value="true"/>
    <insets top="10" bottom="10" left="10" right="10"/>
    <state>
      <color type="BACKGROUND" value="#FFFFFF"/>
      <color type="TEXT_FOREGROUND" value="#000000"/>
    </state>
  </style>
  <bind style="button" type="region" key="Button"/>
</synth>
```